# Comma not found in string with .contains method

Tags: java, string, decimal, bigdecimal

I need to find if a string containes a **comma** or a **dot**.
 
When I use the following code it is working only if I have a **dot** but the comma is not working.
Why ?

```
value is type string.
```

For example :

If I have number like 200 and I wish to add to it **.0** this is fine, but if I my number is like 200,53 it also adds **.0** to it : 200,53.0
Why?

```
if (!value.contains(".") || !value.contains(",")) {
           value = value + ".0";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `&&` ? Because, as I understand, you want to append `.0` if the number doesn't contain BOTH `.` AND `,`

```
if (!value.contains(".") && !value.contains(",")) {
           value = value + ".0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AND(&&) and OR(||) are Short circut operators as per example given by sajan chandran.

this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/506151/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/short-circuit-operators) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using an `||` condition, and due to `Short Circuit` of `OR (||)` if the first `expression` returns `true` the second condition will not get executed at all and that's the reason you are seeing `200,53.0`